# local variable for compare with null

Tags: java

I have found some new code practice (in the guava source code)for me.

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
   Set<K> result = keySet;
   return (result == null) ? keySet = new KeySet() : result;   
}
```

My question is - why there is used local variable resut for comparing with null? Is there any andvantage?

is it not the same like

```
 public Set<K> keySet() {
   return (keySet== null) ? keySet = new KeySet() : keySet;   
 }
```

Comment: Why use a local variable?  Because it's clearer and likely doesn't actually generate any more code.  (In fact, I'd avoid using the triadic operator since it obfuscates in this situation.)

Answer (score 2):

Holding `keySet` in local variable `result` is useful, when:

- the `keySet()` contract does not permit returning `null`;
- at the same time the author does not want to hold on any lock/synchronization
- the `keySet` can be set to `null`

Imagine `keySet` is `volatile`, the reference could have be set to null between checking `keySet==null` and `return keySet`, so there is a chance the second method would return null.

Comment: Of course, if that is possible then neither version is really valid, since the first could result in two threads getting different values.

Comment: In addition, you would also see this style while using `WeakReference.get()` to make sure the object wasn't GCed away.